# How do you use pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_signal()?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I'm very confused on how these two functions work with mutex and what they do. Can someone explain them to me and give an example? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @self. Yes but I didn't really understand it.

Comment: Ask a specific question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pthread_cond_signal() -> This is explain [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html)

More explanation :

You can do a lots of actions with thread, create, remove, make them stop (lock), make them unlock ... ect

pthread_cond_signal() permit to unlock some lock thread.

pthread_cond_wait() is used to lock some thread.

Comment: What would be the difference between pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_cond_wait()?

Comment: pthread_cond_wait() will only lock thread that satisfy the condition (condition is the first parameter of the function)

int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex);